# Is Joomla still a good option for a CMS?

Tags: wordpress, joomla

I have been tasked with making a decision on whether to maintain a current website in Joomla or port it over to something like WordPress. The site currently uses Joomla 1.5 and I have been able to make the immediate updates needed by modifying the template and changing articles as needed. However, to really maintain this site properly I am going to need to understand Joomla a whole lot better, which means an investment of time and resources.

What I am wondering is if it is worth the time invested to delve into Joomla. I have read articles about a lack of leadership, long release/update cycles, and bloated code. Is Joomla in it's current state (v2.5) still competitive when compared to CMS platforms such as WordPress and Drupal? Are the problems mentioned issues of the past? Does Joomla bring any advantages to the table? Or is it pretty much past it's prime and no longer competitive.

I would really like to hear from other developers who are familiar with Joomla. Your thoughts would be helpful in deciding which path to take. Bulk up on Joomla or port it over to WordPress. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 2):

Joomla is really good CMS. 
Its leadership issues have been resolved 2 years back. Now they are following attractive release strategy i.e. every 6 months they release a minor release. Every 18 months they release major version. With all such quick decision and implementation, Joomla is getting ready to explore its full potential.

Once you invest time your time in Joomla, you will love the way it handles lots of functionality. A lot of professional quality extensions are available with Joomla.

Comment: Thanks for the feeback! How difficult is it to write extensions for Joomla? Has performance been improved? Any thoughts on where it exceeds WordPress/Drupal?

Comment: - Its simpler to write extension, but you need to know OOPs

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer may not help you very much. But I will say what I know.
Short answer can be that it depends on your needs but I advice you to study Wordpress and Joomla for a couple days and decide to understand which one
is better for you. 
I have website based on Joomla, I am happy with my choice, however many things I must do manually (edit core files).
Both platform have many good things and couple of bad things.
Good luck.